# How to use printershare application for taking pdf file print from my application?

Tags: android

hello friends,

```
      I am developing an application which has a pdf file and I want to take printout of that file.I want to use printershare application in my application,but I didnt know how to move to that application from my application.
```

And another thing is I want to check whether the application is installed on device or not.

IS it possible to give input to that application like (pdf file as input)?

please help

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

And another thing is I want to check whether the application is installed on device or not.

*You can use try & catch block to figure out if any application which can handle the format is installed already if it's not then you can point the user to download application from playstore in the catch block.*

IS it possible to give input to that application like (pdf file as input)?

*Yes*

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
intent.setDataAndType(path, "application/pdf");
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);


try {
    startActivity(intent);
} 
catch (ActivityNotFoundException e) {
    Toast.makeText(OpenPdf.this, 
        "No Application Available to View PDF", 
        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

// To point the user to playstore

```
 Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("market://details?id=" + packageName));
    intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
    startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: How can I give my custom pdf file in my application to this application(which has to be printed)

Comment: You can use http://www.androlib.com/android.application.com-rcreations-send2printer-jExq.aspx to print PDF directly.

Comment: I am using only the button to take print of my pdf file,so how can I use that send 2 printer.I think that works only when we click directly on pdf file.